# 3 active pages and logical preloading using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, preloading, sections, zepto

i parse pages from a xml-document and build a  for each page. i want to look through these pages like a presentation and slides, so only one section is visible at a time. do keep footprint small, i want to implement logical page preloading. e.g. only the previous, the current and the next section is loaded.

[prev]**[current]**[next]

how can i realize this in jquery or a mobile framework like zepto (jquery-like)? any advice? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have one page visible that is page **n**. You just have to ensure that at all times you load pages **n-1** and **n+1** into memory.

So when you initially load the page you load those 3 and show **n**. Then when you click next you show **n+1** and load **n+2**. The same applies for the previous button.

This doesn't really have anything to do with jQuery or Zepto unless you show us what kind of data you have and in what kind of format you want to show it to us.

At the simplest this can be achieved with a single div and dom nodes stored in an array (memory).

Comment: it's a simple html page including many section tags with images and text. maybe this helps, thanks

Comment: @Tronic is each section related to a page from your xml document? If so then just parse the first 3 sections and keeping parsing new sections as the buttons are called. Add them to the DOM and use [`.show`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) & [`.hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) to deal with only showing one page.

Comment: i will try this, thanks. atm i use a simple ruby parser served by sinatra.

Comment: @Tronic you can try using partial views over ajax with sinatra. I have no experience with sinatra myself but you could set up a service you can call with ajax that returns a particular page so you don't have to preload all pages in ruby at page load.